# Displaying a number based on drop down menu selection

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I created a legend in form of a drop down menu and placed it in a cell.
Is it possible to display a number in the same cell as the drop down menu based on the users selection?

Drop down menu: "10 - Excellent"

I want the cell to display "10"

I know i can achieve this with an If statement, but the one i wrote will be very long because i have a lot of options and a lot of cells.

Thanks,
Anna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a built in way of selecting a value from a dropdown (I am assuming you used data validation features and opted for a list of values or 
pointed to a list of values), and having cell value transformed based on the selected value.

There are a few options I would point out.

**Option 1**
Have a column next to the drop down column where you simply strip out the 
text portion after - Like for example the formula =MID(A1, 1, FIND("-", A1)-1)
assuming Column A is your drop down values.
Of course you will then end up with two columns

[image]

**Option 2**
Use Visual Basic

In your data validation, don't enable error messages if an invalid value is entered. Then use Visual Basic code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If (Target.Column = 1) Then
         Target.Value = Mid(Target.Value, 1, InStr(1, Target.Value, "-") - 1)
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!  Option 2 is more favorable. I am relatively new to VBA coding. what does target.Column = 1 do? does it target the first column in the sheet? can i just change it to the column i need? Similarly, what does Target.value do?   Thanks again!

Comment: Target is the range that is changed. In my sample, column A is the dropdopwn values. You can adjust based on where your column is.
The VB code is also not production ready, you need to fix the code for error handling etc. 
If Target is a range object, Target.Value is the value of the range.
Range in your case is just one cell, (you might want to make sure that range does not contain more than 1 cell), but Target.Value is the cell value, which is the dropdown value the user has selected. The change event fires when the cell value is changed and adjusts the value, and enables events again